# Traefik won't route path

Tags: .net, docker, configuration, traefik, swarm

To test Traefik I have made an app like whoami shown in the Traefik's *getting stated* documentation that responds with a friendly message to a GET HTTP request to '/' and '/sub' endpoints. I've verified that changing whoami to answer through different paths indeed does works but for some reason, Traefik won't resolve my app even though I've configured it similarly as I did with whoami. I know the first thing that comes to mind is that if I've configured my app the same way as I did with whoami so the problem would be my app but curl does confirm that I can reach my app from Traefik's container so it got me wondering if there's something baked into Traefik that whoami app would work and mine wouldn't. I know that's a silly assumption but I don't see what else my app needs to do besides to respond to an HTTP Get request. You can see the app and how I'm bringing everything up [here](https://github.com/rsegecin/traefik_demo), just need to see `build.sh`. Another problem that I did work around it is configuring Traefik in swarm mode which I had to create a Traefik image instead of passing the configuration as an argument. The main configuration shows in the code below and traefik_rp its just an image of traefik with a tom file to set it as sarmMode.

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    # The official v2 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik_rp
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      
  simple_app:
    image: simpleapp
    environment: 
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Release
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.simple_app_service.rule=Path(`/simpleapp`)"

  whoami:
    # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Path(`/`)"
```

Best regards.

Comment: You could add `--log.level=DEBUG` to the `command`-line of `traefik` service and share the configuration logs and any logs when trying a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traefik doesn't clear the route from the HTTP request and it passes the same way it receives to the application. So your application must answer the same route that it's configured on Traefik. The whoami app probably is programmed to spit out HTTP response regardless of the route being accessed meanwhile the app I programmed only answered to the root ('/') path.

Answer (score 2):

Try `PathPrefix` instead of `Path`. Otherwise only exactly `/simpleapp` would be matched. You want `/simpleapp`, `/simpleapp/` and `/simpleapp/sub`.

```
  simple_app:
    image: simpleapp
    environment: 
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Release
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.simple_app_service.rule=PathPrefix(`/simpleapp`)"
```

Also as the other answers suggest, make sure your application handles the `/simpleapp` prefix as well. Otherwise you need to use [StripPrefix](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/stripprefix/).

Answer (score 1):

I checked doc too briefly, but try add this to labels:

```
   labels:
  - traefik.enable=true
  - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https
```

Comment: Hi Karel, thank you for the quick reply, it still gets "HTTP ERROR 404". It's really strange and why whoami app would work if it didn't have to have any additional configuration that could be missing for the app that I'm trying to implement.

Comment: I don't know how looks your "simpleapp". Maybe you need correctly map your ports and also setup traefik network.

Comment: Originally I had added the port number configuration label to my application as it was listening to another port besides the default (80) but just to "identically" set my app like whoami app I've changed it to listen port 80 as well and removed the port label in the compose file. So yes it's correctly mapped.